# Spinning Svg vs Html element - not spining on axis

Tags: html, css, svg

I am wanting to create a logo with a spinning icon in the centre. I have a few paths in it, and just want to spin one of the paths, that i have named on its central axis.  I found many examples online, but couldn't get it to spin on its central axis.

I then have now simplified it to the following code pen.

If I spin a simple div, this works fine.
However if I try to spin a path inside an svg, it does not spin correctly.

What am I missing?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      @keyframes spin {
        from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
        to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
      }
      
      rect {
        animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
      }

      #rect{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="rect" style="background-color: blue; border: solid thin black;"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width='100' height='100' fill="green" stroke="black" />
    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sianabanana2/pen/JjRrjYG)

Comment: `transform-origin: center;
    transform-box: fill-box;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this selector with your `<style>...</style>` tag:

```
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

Also, override the default `transform-origin` rule for `rect`:

```
rect {
  ...
  transform-origin: unset;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
  overflow: overlay;
}

rect {
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: unset;
}

#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rect" style="background-color: blue; border: solid thin black;"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width='100' height='100' fill="green" stroke="black" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```